How do I properly dispose expired objects in MemoryCache (it may still be in used)?
I understand items in MemoryCache are not disposed when expired. I am caching some X509Certificate2 which according to the documentation, should be disposed when done.
However, my naive approach would dispose the object when the object may still be used by some threads (see code below).
How do I correctly handle this case? I think I may need a reference count or something similar?
await cache.GetOrCreateAsync("IdTokenCerts", async entry =>
        {
            entry.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = JwtCertsCacheLifetime;
            entry.RegisterPostEvictionCallback((_, value, _, _) =>
            {
                if (value is IEnumerable<SecurityKey> keys)
                {
                    foreach (var key in keys)
                    {
                        if (key is X509SecurityKey x509Key)
                        {
                            x509Key.Certificate.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            // ...
        }


Maybe a wrapper that is aware of references and so can defer disposal until it is either unreferenced on eviction or the last reference disposes it after eviction? Whichever happens first.

@Fildor yes, that's what I am implementing right now though I think maybe there is some built-in API for such a task?

Not that I am aware of. Sounds a bit like a special case of an object pool rather than a cache , actually...

I am not sure if I misunderstand the terminology but I don't think this is a pool. All data becomes "stale" after a while and I have to fetch new data and dispose the old one. The old ones don't actually return and get reused. Anyway, I implemented a simple tracker :)

I implemented a simple tracker like this:
public class UsageTracker<TData>(TData data)
{

    public event EventHandler OnDisposed = delegate { };

    public bool DisposeRequested { get; private set; }

    public TData Data => data;
    public int UsageCount { get; private set; }

    public void RequestDispose()
    {
        if (DisposeRequested) { return; }

        DisposeRequested = true;
        CheckForDispose();
    }

    public UsageTrackerItem<TData> RequestUsage()
    {
        if (DisposeRequested)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(nameof(UsageTracker<TData>));
        }

        UsageCount++;
        return new UsageTrackerItem<TData>(this, data);
    }

    internal void OnItemDisposed()
    {
        UsageCount--;
        CheckForDispose();
    }

    void CheckForDispose()
    {
        if (UsageCount == 0 && DisposeRequested)
        {
            OnDisposed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

}

public class UsageTrackerItem<TData> : IDisposable
{
    readonly UsageTracker<TData> tracker;
    public TData Data { get; private set; }

    internal UsageTrackerItem(UsageTracker<TData> tracker, TData data)
    {
        this.tracker = tracker;
        Data = data;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        tracker.OnItemDisposed();
    }
}

Usage:
var data = 5;
var tracker = new UsageTracker<int>(data);

// Test tracker
tracker.OnDisposed += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine("Code for disposing items should be here");

var task = Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(async i =>
{
    using var data = tracker.RequestUsage();
    await Task.Delay(Random.Shared.Next(1000, 5000));

    Console.WriteLine($"Task {i} completed. {tracker.UsageCount} usages remaining.");
}));

tracker.RequestDispose();
Console.WriteLine("Tracker disposal requested");

try
{
    using var staleData = tracker.RequestUsage();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("There should be this exception due to requesting data after requesting disposal:");
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}

await task;

Output:
Tracker disposal requested
There should be this exception due to requesting data after requesting disposal:
Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'UsageTracker'.
Task 7 completed. 10 usages remaining.
Task 2 completed. 9 usages remaining.
Task 0 completed. 8 usages remaining.
Task 9 completed. 7 usages remaining.
Task 1 completed. 6 usages remaining.
Task 5 completed. 6 usages remaining.
Task 8 completed. 4 usages remaining.
Task 4 completed. 3 usages remaining.
Task 6 completed. 2 usages remaining.
Task 3 completed. 1 usages remaining.
Code for disposing items should be here


Where is Dispose called on the tracked item? Maybe I missed it.

@Fildor In the production code, it should be called at tracker.OnDisposed += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine("Data actually disposed");. In this demo, instead of calling Dispose, I simply write it out into the console. My bad I guess that sentence isn't very clear, I will edit to clarify.

What I would do is constrain TData with : IDisposable and then instead of relying on the consumer to do it, call ((IDisposable)Data).Dispose(); when appropriate ... just to have a defined behavior that I can test for and safely assume.

@Fildor that's my initial approach too but in my case, it's actually a whole IEnumerable<X509SecurityKey> that I was caching and when I need to dispose it, I need to dispose each item's certificate and IEnumerable is not an IDisposable. This way, I give more flexibility of what to do when I need to actually dispose such TData.

Ah, ok. I didn't know that. Yeah, then it makes sense.
